# Sub query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mysql query. How do i model this query in elasticsearch?
Query is-

```
select targetId from mytable where actorId=? and targetId in (select actorId from mytable where targetId = ?)
```

mytable has only two columns actorId and targetId. 
Currently I am running inner query separately and passing the result to outer query. Is there a way to do it in one shot.My elasticsearch query is as follows.

```
{
"filtered" : {
    "query" : {
     "match_all" : { }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "term" : {
            "actorId" : 3432079
          }
        }, 
        {
          "not" : {
            "filter" : {
              "terms" : {
                "targetId" : [3435089, 3435093]
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
Instead of above i want to do it as follows

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
         "match_all" : { }
        },
        "filter" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "term" : {
                "actorId" : 3432079
              }
            }, 
            {
              "not" : {
                "filter" : {
                  "terms" : {
                    "targetId" : (inner query which returns target ids)
                  }
                }
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a few sample documents so that people can recreate the issue?

Comment: @Val I edited the question, does it clarify the point?

Comment: no you can't do that directly with elasticsearch queries